# Which Canon DSLR models have sRAW/mRAW support?

Tags: canon, raw

What Canon models do have support for smaller RAW (sRAW, mRAW) sizes?

Seems the EOS 60D does, but the 600D and 650D doesn't ... is there a list? Is this not a standard feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is a feature of all 2-digit models and  1-digit models since about 2007.**

This is a Canon only feature. I do not know of anyone who uses it honestly since those who shoot RAW do it to get all sensor information.

Comment: If I had a camera with 16 megapixels or more and this feature, I would certainly look into it. I rarely need that level of raw resolution — and I don't really enjoy the level of meticulous technical precision it requires to take advantage of it anyway. I know it's not quite as flexible as full RAW, but for the kind of adjustments I tend to make it seems like a reasonable compromise.